# Adjust size value in Material UI

Tags: javascript, css, material-ui

Assuming I am suing the `<Rating />` component https://mui.com/material-ui/api/rating/.

I can set its size with the `size prop`. But where do I define the actual values for size `small`, `medium` and `large`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Styled Rating:

```
<StyledRating
  name="customized-color"
  defaultValue={2}
  precision={0.5}
  icon={
    <StarIcon
      style={{ width: "50px", height: "50px" }}
      fontSize="inherit"
    />
  }
  emptyIcon={
    <StarOutlineIcon
      style={{ width: "50px", height: "50px" }}
      fontSize="inherit"
    />
  }
/>
```

You can get the full codes from this link [Star Rating](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-poincare-w4hwm2?file=/demo.tsx)